# Angularjs not visualizing first option in input select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In Angularjs, binding input select to the model creates new empty option

```
<option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
```

And this is the code

```
<select name="category" ng-model="hotspot.category">
  <option>Culture</option>
  <option>Education</option>
  <option>Parks</option>
  <option>Student Pubs</option>
</select>
```

Is this normal? It doesn't seem to be something good looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have initialized your model variable with one of the option value.

Try this

**Controller**

```
$scope.hotspot = {};
$scope.hotspot.category = "Culture";
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="category" ng-model="hotspot.category">
  <option>Culture</option>
  <option>Education</option>
  <option>Parks</option>
  <option>Student Pubs</option>
</select>
```